# Match ID based on priority - SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I need to match the ID's based on priority from another table. Which would be the efficient and best way to do this?

```
Table 1:

cd  priority
1     10

2     20

3     30

4     40

5     50


Table 2: 

ID    cd 
1001  2

1001  4

1001  5

1002  1

1002  3 

1002  5

1003  6

Expected Output: 

ID     cd 
1001      2

1002      1
```

I have mentioned what i have tried, but wanted to know if there is any functions in hive/spark with which we can take advantage of, for this scenario.

```
select * from (select tb1.cd, tb2.id , tb1.priority, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tb2.id ORDER BY tb1.priority ) rnk
from Table1  tb1
inner join 
Table2 tb2
on tb1.cd = tb2.cd) a
where a.rnk =1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, it seems that the first table will be small enough to fit into memory. If so, ensure that spark broadcasts it in order to perform the join.

You can use `explain` to view the plan that spark generates. If you do not see Broadcasting being done there, specify a hint while executing your query.

Hope it helps!